# How to add the padding and margin options for Gutenberg?

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

I found the font size and color setting using [your_theme.gutenberg.yml](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/gutenberg/creating-custom-font-size-presets-in-a-theme). Is there a similar setting where I can enable the padding and margin options? If not, what's the right way to add the padding option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by setting `enableCustomSpacing: true` in the custom_theme.gutenberg.yml.

Make sure to place it under `theme-support`

Comment: Thank you, @Hodba Khalaf. "Column" spacing can be customized with enableCustomSpacing. Are there any settings for "Columns"(the Column parent)?